# Exporting/Importing Users from/into WSO2IS User Store in bulk

Tags: import, bulk, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to export all my users from one identity server instance to another. This includes all the roles that these users are part of, their permissions and claims. 
What is the best way to export these users in bulk, and then importing them in another WSO2IS instance? The WSO2IS documentation is very limited about this subject: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Users#ConfiguringUsers-Importingusers

Both IS instances have a postgres jdbc DB and have it running as a primary user store.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use separate databases for different IS instances. Otherwise you can just configure the same database in the new IS instance.

If you want to use a separate database, exporting the database dump from current user store database and importing to the new one/ create new using the dump should work.

Comment: Thanx for your response @Lahiru, however this is not an ideal solution. What happens when the database structure gets altered in a next version of IS? I would run the risk that my dB renders useless...

Comment: Yes, most probably in the major releases database structure may altered. Then you have the migration scripts to do the migration. May be i did not get the requirement. What do you mean by 'I would run the risk that my dB renders useless'?

Comment: Thanx, I did not think of the migration scripts. I was just hoping for a more automated way of exporting just the users and their related tables.